# Whats the best pattern/practise to work with WebFlux ClientResponse?

Tags: spring-webflux

There are a lot of articles about using .exchange() and most of them recommend to close connection using
bodyToMono*, toEntity*, or just ClientResponse.close() or sometimes ClientResponse.dispose()
I am a little bit confused because ClientReponse interface in my project (spring-webflux:5.1.9.Release) doesn't have a method close();.

I need to check httpStatus (that's the only reason why I am using .exchange() but not .retrieve()), there is also some logic with "bad" httpStatus (I am throwing custom error and then process it in .onErrorResume() block)

So what is the best practise to work with clientResponse()?
If the only problem is that the App doesn't know when it should close the connection, will .exchange().block() automatically close the connection ?
If I should use .close() - how should I get this method ? Maybe I should use another version of spring-webflux ?
Or maybe there is another best way to retrieve response body and status in spring-webflux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is anything as "best practice" in this scenario . It totally depends on your requirements. Like you are throwing custom error on 4xx status, that's why you are using exchange.

Regarding ClientResponse.dispose() / ClientResponse.close() **there is no such method** in the documentation.

This is from the official [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ClientResponse.html)

[image]

Comment: thanks! I didnt have this method either, after update webflux to 5.2.7. like in the doc you post, it appeared.
When i get a clientResponse - i should release it, but when exchange() method send error signal due to connection problems - should i release some sources in this case ?